# Find all lines in a file with a certain character at a certain position

Tags: bash

I want, that my bash script counts the lines of a .txt file, which starts with an '#'.

`grep -o "#" $FILE | wc -l`

I know how to count all lines with a '#' in it but I dont know how to implement the condition, that the '#' needs to be at the start of the program.

The Input are other bash scripts. I want to count how many comments are in the different bash scripts. Than I want to divide the output with the total numbers of lines in the txt file. So I have a percentage of how many lines of the bash script are comments. Like if I have 10 lines of comments in a 100 lines code, 10% of the code are comments.

I also want to scan these lines starting with a '#' after a certain word like "Hello" and count how many lines having this word. Hope someone can help me there too :).

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: The Input are other bash scripts. I want to count how many comments are in the different bash scripts. Than I want to divide the output with the total numbers of lines in the txt file. So I have a percentage of how many lines of the bash script are comments. Like if I have 10 lines of comments in a 100 lines code, 10% of the code are comments.

Comment: Don't just describe your input, **show** us a [mcve] with sample input and the expected output given that input. We need you to provide something we can copy/paste to test with. See [ask].

Comment: Well an input could be:

`#!/bin/bash`
`#Write the line Hello`
`echo "Hello"`
`#Exit it`
`exit 1`

But as I said, it can be some random Bash code...
The output of the this need to be 3, because 3 lines start with a "#".
But I need to implement, that the line with the shebang doesnt count, because its not a comment. But I think I can do it myself.

Comment: what about lines like `<whitespace>#...`, `echo "#this is not a comment"`; the line `echo "hello world" #this is a comment` contains a command and a comment so technically shouldn't be counted when calculating the % of code that are comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count all the lines that start with a `#` by doing:

```
grep -c "^#" $FILE
```

Or after a certain word (with 0 or more other characters between) by doing:

```
grep -c "Hello.*#" $FILE
```